# How to make a FAST synchronous request on Node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, httprequest, synchronous

I have converted a program using synchronous(http request) call from client side(using ajax) to server side(Nodejs). After that, the program takes 4 times longer than it took.

I get 'undefined' as return of the function when I use asynchronous call.
So, I have tried two ways of synchronous call, and both takes too long time.

Is there good ways to get 'body_return' in the function below, using async call?
Or, using FAST sync call?

```
function getBody(input) {

  //sync call-TRY.1
  var body_return;
  request(option, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

       //do something with body;
       body_return = dosomething(body);
     }
  });

  //sync call-TRY.2
  var body = sync_request('POST', '(uri)', options).getBody('utf8');
  var body_return = dosomething(body);

  //async call can't return the body in time, so this function returns undefined..

  return body_return;
}
```

Comment: How did you determine that it takes 4 times longer?

Comment: @robertklep I checked log time using Date.now() before/after the code.

Comment: I doubt it's related to the Node.js request being async, but because of missing context (what did the client-side code look like, what is the URL that you're requesting, etc) it's difficult to say why the Node code seems slower.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns `undefined` because of asynchronous nature of node.js.
You should return `body_return` inside `callback of request` when you actually get the response.

```
function getBody(input) {

//this is async call
  var body_return;
  request(option, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

   //do something with body;
   body_return = dosomething(body);

   //return when you get the response
   return body_return;
 }

  });  
}
```

Comment: I already tried your solution. Your code also returns undefined. I want 'getBody()' function to wait for the request, but it doen't wait for it.